# Disable animation on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to activate this animation when the html page with this code is loaded and when i click to another Ajax page tab i want to disable this because at the moment this animation animate the div on every ajax page and i want to load this only on the specific page.

How is that possible?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
    $(".example").animate({
        top: "0px"
    }, {
        duration: 50,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
    });
} else {
    $(".example").animate({
        top: "-50px"
    }, {
        duration: 50,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Just add the script in page you want.

Comment: nope the html are loaded via ajax in one html file so thats not possible :/

Comment: Add a variable in your page you are loading via AJAX `var enableAnimation = false` and check for the variable in you `$(window).scroll` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using hashes for your Ajax page you can easily check this to see if you are on the page before executing the animation like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "foobar"){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
        $(".example").animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, {
            duration: 50,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
        });
    } else {
        $(".example").animate({
            top: "-50px"
        }, {
            duration: 50,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
        });
    }
}
});
```

Note that you will have to make sure that once you change a page. You also change the hash:

```
window.location.hash = "foobar";
```

Comment: How I can define more that one hash for that animation? if(hash == "foobar", "example2") this is not working :/

Comment: you would do this with a simple or-statement: `if(hash == "foobar" || hash == "example2")`

Comment: this is not working :/ the animation is now buggy slide to 0 then to -60 then 0 then -60 :D